# Memory issue with JAX RS using jersey

Tags: java, performance, rest, jersey, java-memory-leaks

We currently have some trouble on a productive server as it consumes way too much memory. One of the leaks could come from the jersey client. I found the following two other questions and a how to:

1. [How to correctly share JAX-RS 2.0 client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34566278/how-to-correctly-share-jax-rs-2-0-client)
2. [Closing JAX RS Client/Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33083961/closing-jax-rs-client-response)
3. https://blogs.oracle.com/japod/entry/how_to_use_jersey_client

What I get from it, I should reuse the Client and potentially also the WebTargets?
Also closing responses is advised, but how can I do this with .request()?

Code example, this is getting called about 1000 times per hour with different paths:

```
public byte[] getDocument(String path) {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    WebTarget target = client.target(config.getPublishHost() + path);
    try {
        byte[] bytes = target.request().get(byte[].class);
        LOGGER.debug("Document size in bytes: " + bytes.length);
        return bytes;
    } catch (ProcessingException e) {
        LOGGER.error(Constants.PROCESSING_ERROR, e);
        throw new FailureException(Constants.PROCESSING_ERROR, e);
    } catch (WebApplicationException e) {
        LOGGER.error(Constants.RESPONSE_ERROR, e);
        throw new FailureException(Constants.RESPONSE_ERROR, e);
    } finally {
        client.close();
    }
}
```

**So my question is how to properly use the API to prevent leaks for the above example?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### `Client` instances should be reused

[`Client`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html) instances are *heavy-weight* objects that manage the underlying client-side communication infrastructure. Hence initialization as well as disposal of a [`Client`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html) instance may be a rather expensive operation.

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html) advises to create only a *small number* of [`Client`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html) instances and *reuse them when possible*. It also states that [`Client`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html) instances must be *properly closed before being disposed* to avoid leaking resources.

### `WebTarget` instances could be reused

You could reuse [`WebTarget`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/WebTarget.html) instances if you perform multiple requests to the same path. And reusing [`WebTarget`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/WebTarget.html) instances is recommended if they have some [configuration](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Configurable.html).

### `Response` instances should be closed if you don't read the entity

[`Response`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html) instances that contain an un-consumed entity input stream *should be closed*. This is typical for scenarios where only the response headers and the status code are processed, *ignoring the response entity*. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35265704/1426227) for more details on closing [`Response`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html) instances.

### Improving your code

For the situation mentioned in your question, you want you ensure that the [`Client`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html) instance is reused for all `getDocument(String)` method invocations.

For instance, if your application is CDI based, create a [`Client`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html) instance when the bean is constructed and dispose it before its destruction. In the example below, the [`Client`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html) instance is stored in a singleton bean:

```
@Singleton
public class MyBean {

    private Client client;

    @PostConstruct
    public void onCreate() {
        this.client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    }

    ...

    @PreDestroy
    public void onDestroy() {
        this.client.close();
    }
}
```

You don't need to (or maybe you can't) reuse the [`WebTarget`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/WebTarget.html) instance (the requested path changes for each method invocation). And the [`Response`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html) instance is automatically closed when you read the entity into a `byte[]`.

#### Using a connection pool

A connection pool can be a good performance improvement.

As mentioned in my older [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38873392/1426227), by default, the transport layer in Jersey is provided by [`HttpURLConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html). This support is implemented in Jersey via [`HttpUrlConnectorProvider`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/2.26/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/client/HttpUrlConnectorProvider.html). You can replace the default connector if you want to and use a connection pool for better performance.

Jersey integrates with Apache HTTP Client via the [`ApacheConnectorProvider`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/2.26/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/apache/connector/ApacheConnectorProvider.html). To use it, add the following dependecy:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.connectors</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-apache-connector</artifactId>
    <version>2.26</version>
</dependency>
```

And then create your [`Client`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html) instance as following:

```java
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = 
        new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
connectionManager.setMaxTotal(100);
connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(5);

ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
clientConfig.property(ApacheClientProperties.CONNECTION_MANAGER, connectionManager);
clientConfig.connectorProvider(new ApacheConnectorProvider());

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);
```

For additional details, refer to [Jersey documentation about connectors](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#connectors).

Comment: jee singleton by default does not allow concurent access. So if you propose to configure thread pool for Client, then add `@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.BEAN)` to the class. Otherwise it does not make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following example in this link to close Response on `completed` method: https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/async.html#d0e10209

```
    final Future<Response> responseFuture = target().path("http://example.com/resource/")
            .request().async().get(new InvocationCallback<Response>() {
                @Override
                public void completed(Response response) {
                    System.out.println("Response status code "
                            + response.getStatus() + " received.");
                    //here you can close the response
                }
     
                @Override
                public void failed(Throwable throwable) {
                    System.out.println("Invocation failed.");
                    throwable.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
```

### tip 1 (Response or String):

You can close the response only when it is from type of `Response` class, not : `String`.

### tip 2 (Auto-closing):

Referring to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25196427/how-to-retrieve-json-response-from-a-javax-ws-rs-core-response-response), When you read the entity, the response will be closed automatically:

```
String responseAsString = response.readEntity(String.class);
```

### tip 3 (connection pooling):

Referring to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38872832/how-does-http-connection-pooling-work-in-work-in-jersey), you can use connection-pools to have better performance. example:

```
public static JerseyClient getInstance() {
    return InstanceHolder.INSTANCE;
}

private static class InstanceHolder {
    private static final JerseyClient INSTANCE = createClient();

    private static JerseyClient createClient() {
        ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();

        clientConfig.property(ClientProperties.ASYNC_THREADPOOL_SIZE, 200);

        clientConfig.property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, 10000);
        clientConfig.property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 10000);

        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();

        connectionManager.setMaxTotal(200);
        connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(100);
        clientConfig.property(ApacheClientProperties.CONNECTION_MANAGER, connectionManager);
        clientConfig.connectorProvider(new ApacheConnectorProvider());

        JerseyClient client = JerseyClientBuilder.createClient(clientConfig);
        //client.register(RequestLogger.requestLoggingFilter);
        return client;
    }
}
```

**ATTENTION!** By using this solution, if you don't close the response, you can not send more than 100 requests to server (`setDefaultMaxPerRoute(100)`)

Comment: Using a static member for the `Client` instance seems to be a good idea, but looks like the `Client` instance gets never closed.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin: thank you. depends on the needs I think. in my solution the rest client is needed always.